# Render dynamic array of components

Tags: blazor

I am new to Blazor. Aiming to understand it better, I am trying to create a simple page that renders some SVG shapes dynamically, from an array.

I have this page:

```
@page "/myshapespage"

<MySvg />
```

Here's MySvg:

```
<svg width="1000" height="600" name="theSvg" id="theSvg" viewBox="0 0 1000 600">
    <Circle X="100" Y="100" Radius="30" />
    <Square X="130" Y="210" Side="55" />
    <Circle X="300" Y="400" Radius="15" />
    <Square X="230" Y="210" Side="25" />
</svg>
```

Here are the Circle and the Square, deriving from a common Shape:

Shape:

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public float X { get; set; } = 0;

    [Parameter]
    public float Y { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Circle:

```
@inherits Shape

<circle cx="@X" cy="@Y" r="@Radius" fill="blue" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public float Radius { get; set; } = 20;
}
```

Square:

```
@inherits Shape

    <rect x="@X" y="@Y" width="@Side" height="@Side" fill="green" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public float Side { get; set; } = 25;
}
```

This works fine and I can see a page with an SVG and two blue circles and two green squares. **However**, I would like to be able to display a dynamic array of shapes, and the user should be able to add shapes at runtime. MySvg should have an array of Shapes that it goes and renders dynamically.

So I was trying to get something like this working:

```
svg width="1000" height="600" name="theSvg" id="theSvg" viewBox="0 0 1000 600">
    <Circle X="100" Y="100" Radius="30" />
    <Square X="130" Y="210" Side="55" />
    <Circle X="300" Y="400" Radius="15" />
    <Square X="230" Y="210" Side="25" />
    @{
        RenderMoreShapes();     // ???
    }
</svg>

@code {
    Shape[] theShapes =
        {
            new Square{X = 50, Y = 50, Side= 10},
            new Square{X = 150, Y = 150, Side= 15},
            new Square{X = 200, Y = 200, Side= 200},
            new Circle{X = 30, Y = 30, Radius = 5},
            new Circle{X = 60, Y = 60, Radius = 10},
            new Circle{X = 90, Y = 90, Radius = 15}
    };

    void RenderMoreShapes()
    {
        foreach (var shape in theShapes)
        {
            // ???
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to work with some `RenderFragment` or `RenderTreeBuilder` but could not get these to work with this approach.

I do not want to write the rendering code inside MySvg. Each shape knows how to render itself, and I want the rendering code to remain encapsulated in each shape. I am likely misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't initialize or manage Components: the Renderer does.

You need to separate out your data from the your component.

First an interface and some records to define your shapes.  Keep these lightweight.

```cs
public interface ISvg
{
    public float X { get;}
    public float Y { get;}
}

public record Circle(float X, float Y, float Radius) : ISvg;

public record Square(float X, float Y, float Side) : ISvg;
```

A minimal collection to hold and manage the shapes.  You can add more functionality.

```cs
public class MySvgs : IEnumerable<ISvg>
{
    private readonly List<ISvg> _items = new();

    public void AddSvg(ISvg value)
        => _items.Add(value);

    public IEnumerator<ISvg> GetEnumerator()
        => _items.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => _items.GetEnumerator();
}
```

The Svg container component.  Note using type switching to handle the different shapes in the render fragment.

```cs
<h3>Svg Container</h3>

<svg width="800" height="600" name="theSvg" id="theSvg" viewBox="0 0 800 600">
    @foreach (var svg in this.Svgs)
    {
        @GetShape(svg)
    }
</svg>

@code {
    [Parameter] public MySvgs Svgs { get; set; } = new();

    RenderFragment<ISvg> GetShape => (shape) => (__builder) =>
    {
        switch (shape)
        {
            case Circle circleValue:
                <circle cx="@circleValue.X" cy="@circleValue.Y" r="@circleValue.Radius" fill="blue" />
                break;

            case Square squareValue:
                <rect x="@squareValue.X" y="@squareValue.Y" width="@squareValue.Side" height="@squareValue.Side" fill="green" />
                break;
        };
    };
}
```

And a Demo Page:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>SVG Demo</h1>

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="AddShape">Add a Shape</button>
</div>

<SvgContainer Svgs="_svgs" />

@code {
    private MySvgs _svgs = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _svgs.AddSvg(new Circle(100, 100, 30));
        _svgs.AddSvg(new Square(200, 300, 30));
        _svgs.AddSvg(new Circle(600, 300, 55));
        _svgs.AddSvg(new Square(400, 100, 55));
    }

    private void AddShape()
    {
        _svgs.AddSvg(new Square(20, 200, 300));
    }
}
```

I've added a button to demo how to add a new shape. You need to write editor code to manually add shapes.

> I do not want to write the rendering code inside MySvg

My code above doesn't do that as it's not necessary.  If that's what you want then add the components to the render fragment.

Comment: Than you so much, you've got me on the right track.